# Apart from Togepi and Ho-oH, What out-of-season pokemon have there been?

Tags: pokemon

In the first episode of pokemon, Ash sees a Ho-oH flying overhead, yet it wasn't known about (at least by Prof. Oak) until the second generation of pokemon.

[image]

When Ash hatches a Pokemon egg and gets Togepi in "who gets to keep Togepi", the pokedex comes up with nothing apart from a name.

[image]

Are there any other pokemon we get to see prior to their generation's season of the anime? (Up to generation 5)

Comment: Do you want occurrences in side-media like *Pikachu's Vacation* too? (Ex: Marill, Snubbull)

Comment: Sure, but mostly the main series

Comment: I think as long as the series is going on, it fails at least point 4: http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/348/what-is-the-status-of-list-questions-on-this-site Also I don't know whether its reasonably scoped, as there could be too many occurrences.

Comment: Limiting it to gen 5 Pokemon, does that work?

Comment: @looper: I don't think there will be too many occurrences, and I also don't think it requires frequent update (maybe once a few years?). However, the scope is indeed quite big, considering how many years the series has been running.

Comment: http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/User:Caciulacdlac/Pok%C3%A9mon_that_appeared_before_their_generation

Comment: @nhahtdh While it's hard to tell if that list is complete, you might as well post it as an answer since it's better than what anyone here is likely to do. I doubt anyone here is going to to watch nearly 800 episodes plus movies and specials to just to find what entries are missing (if any).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

User Caciulacdlac on Bulbapedia has compiled [a list of Pokemon that appeared before their generation starts airing](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/User%3aCaciulacdlac/Pok%C3%A9mon_that_appeared_before_their_generation). I assume the Japan broadcast date is used as the criteria.

The whole answer below is mostly based on the link above, and several other articles on Bulbapedia.

---

All the dates cited below will be **Japan** broadcast dates. Episode numbering will follow the numbering used by Bulbapedia.

**Generation II**

Episode 117, aired on **October 14, 1999**, marks the start of the [*The Johto Journeys*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon%3a_The_Johto_Journeys) (season 3), and also the start of generation II. The Pokemon listed below are from generation II, but appeared in the anime before the journey to Johto started.

- **Ho-Oh**: [Episode 001: *Pokémon - I Choose You!*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP001) **(April 1, 1997)**
- **Togepi**: [Episode 050: *Who Gets to Keep Togepi?*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP050) **(June 25, 1998)**
- **Marill**, **Snubbull**: [Pikachu Shorts 01: *Pikachu's Vacation*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/PK01) **(July 18, 1998)**
- **Donphan**: [Movies 01: *Mewtwo Strikes Back*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/M01) **(July 18, 1998)**
- **Ledyba**, **Elekid**<sup>1</sup>, **Bellossom**, **Hoothoot**: [Pikachu Shorts 04: *Pikachu's Rescue Adventure*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/PK04) **(July 17, 1999)**
  <sub><sup>1</sup> Elekid also appeared earlier in Tracey's sketch in [Episode 103 - *Misty Meets Her Match*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP103) **(July 1, 1999)**</sub>
- **Lugia**, **Slowking**: [Movies 2: *The Power of One*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/M02) **(July 17, 1999)**

**Generation III**

The first episode of [*Advanced Generation*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Advanced_Generation_series) series, aired on **November 21, 2002**, marks the start of [*Pokémon: Advanced*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon%3a_Advanced) season (season 6), and also the start of generation III. The Pokemon listed below are from generation III, but appeared in the anime before generation III (to Hoenn) started.

- **Kecleon**: [Episode 205: *The Kecleon Caper*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP205) **(July 5, 2001)**
- **Azurill**, **Wailmer**: [Pikachu Shorts 10: *Pikachu's PikaBoo*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/PK10) **(July 7, 2001)**
- **Wynaut**: [Episode 252: *Fangs for Nothin'*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP252) **(June 13, 2002)**
- **Duskull**, **Volbeat**: [Pikachu Shorts 11: *Camp Pikachu*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/PK11) **(July 13, 2002)**
- **Latias**, **Latios**: [Movies 05: *Pokémon Heroes*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/M05) **(July 13, 2002)**
- **Blaziken**: [Episode 265: *Pop Goes The Sneasel*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP265) **(September 12, 2002)**
- **Sharpedo**, **Seedot**, **Shroomish**, **Lotad**, **Zigzagoon**: [Episode 272: *Johto Photo Finish*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP272) **(October 31, 2002)**
- **Wingull**, **Pelipper**: [Episode 274: *Hoenn Alone!*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP274) **(November 14, 2002)**

**Generation IV**

The first episode of [*Diamond and Pearl*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Diamond_%26_Pearl_series) series, aired on **September 28, 2006**, marks the start of [*Pokemon: Diamond and Pearl*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon%3a_Diamond_and_Pearl) season (season 10) and also the start of generation IV. The Pokemon listed below are from generation IV, but appeared in the anime before the journey to Sinnoh started.

- **Munchlax**: [Movies 07: *Destiny Deoxys*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/M07) **(July 17, 2004)**
- **Lucario**, **Bonsly**, **Weavile**, **Mime Jr.**: [Movies 08: *Lucario and the Mystery of Mew*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/M08) **(July 16, 2005)**
- **Manaphy**, **Mantyke**, **Buizel**, **Chatot**: [Movies 09: *Pokémon Ranger and the Temple of the Sea*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/M09) **(July 15, 2006)**
- **Electivire**: [Advanced Generation Episode 192: *Home is Where the Start Is!*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/AG192) **(September 14, 2006)**

**Generation V**

The first episode of [*Best Wishes*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Best_Wishes_series) series, aired on **September 23, 2010**, marks the start of generation V. The Pokemon listed below are from generation V, but appeared in the anime before the journey to Unova started.

- **Zorua, Zoroark, Woobat**<sup>2</sup>: [Movies 13: *Zoroark: Master of Illusions*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/M13) **(July 10, 2010)**
  <sub><sup>2</sup> Appeared as image only.</sub>

**Generation VI**

The first episode of [*XY Series*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/XY_series), aired on **October 17, 2013**, marks the start of generation VI. The Pokemon listed below are from generation VI, but appeared in the anime before the journey to Kalos started.

- **Sylveon**: [Pikachu Shorts 25: Eevee & Friends](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/PK25) **(July 13, 2013)**
- **Helioptile, Gogoat**: [Best Wishes Episode 134: The Journalist from Another Region!](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/BW134) **(July 18, 2013)**
- **Noivern**: [Best Wishes Episode 137: Celebrating the Hero's Comet!](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/BW137) **(August 15, 2013)**

Comment: Wasn't Marrill's first appearance in the main series during the Orange Islands arc before that short?

Answer (score -1):

Snubbull was introduced in 1998 in the Pikachu special, Pikachu's vacation. It was not until the year 2000 that the Generation 2 pokemon were introduced.