# In the Johto-based movie Pokémon Heroes, why do Latias/Latios appear?

Tags: pokemon

Upon organizing my Pokemon movies chronologically I became confused as to where this movie lies. There was more evidence such as Misty's and Brock's presence as well as Totodile (Johto water starter) and Xatu/Natu (Pokemon introduced in Gen II as well) and thus I concluded the movie was more 'Johto' in the sense. So then why do Latias and Latios, the Eon duo of the 'Hoenn' region, make an appearnce? This feels like a vital chronological flaw and it's messing with my current knowledge of the Pokémon anime.

Comment: Strongly related: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4145/apart-from-togepi-and-ho-oh-what-out-of-season-pokemon-have-there-been

Answer (score 1):

In the Pokemon movie series, there's been always a group of films by the order of the Pokemon anime series, which will go by that - Original Series (Indigo, Orange and Johto League), Advance, Diamond and Pearl and so on by the anime series have a number of films for each season, so the original series goes by 5 seasons, so it has 5 films, and so on. the usual thing of the OLM studio in the last films upon a pokemon season film is to feature pokemon from the Next Gen. (with few exceptions), by this list here:

**Original series films**

**Orange season** - "Pokémon: The Movie 2000 - The Power of One", features Lugia which is a 2nd gen legendary pokemon. (while the anime season is still about the 1st gen)

**Johto season** - "Pokémon Heroes: Latios and Latias" feature Latios and Latia from the 3rd gen.

**Advanced Generation** films

"Lucario and the Mystery of Mew" and "Pokémon Ranger and the Temple of the Sea" featuring 4th gen pokemon: Lucario and Menaphy

**Diamond & Pearl** films

"Zoroark—Master of Illusions" - featuring Zoroark and Zorua from the 5th gen.

soucre: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_films)

Ass Turamarth commented this q&a answers much as I did: [Apart from Togepi and Ho-oH, What out-of-season pokemon have there been?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4145/apart-from-togepi-and-ho-oh-what-out-of-season-pokemon-have-there-been)

And you also might want to see this: [When do the Pokemon Movies occur chronologically to the plot?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/35757/when-do-the-pokemon-movies-occur-chronologically-to-the-plot)

PS. in the movie you mentioned, there's also a racer with a Wailmer, which is to from the 3rd gen, but it has nothing to do with the answer just a side note.